# Facing issue while installing windows server 2022 and visual studio 2022 into images can not able test MSTest

Tags: docker, image, visual-studio, dockerfile, containers

Facing issue while installing windows server 2022 and visual studio 2022 in container

I am using the below Dokerfile

```
# escape=`

# Use the latest Windows Server Core 2019 image.
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2022

# Restore the default Windows shell for correct batch processing.
SHELL ["cmd", "/S", "/C"]

RUN `
    # Download the Build Tools bootstrapper.
    curl -SL --output vs_enterprise.exe https://aka.ms/vs/17/release/vs_enterprise.exe `
    `
    # Install Build Tools with the Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.AzureBuildTools workload, excluding workloads and components with known issues.
    && (start /w vs_enterprise.exe --quiet --wait --norestart --nocache `
        --installPath "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise" `
        --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.AzureBuildTools `
        --remove Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows10SDK.10240 `
        --remove Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows10SDK.10586 `
        --remove Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows10SDK.14393 `
        --remove Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows81SDK `
        || IF "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="3010" EXIT 0) `
    `
    # Cleanup
    && del /q vs_enterprise.exe

# Define the entry point for the docker container.
# This entry point starts the developer command prompt and launches the PowerShell shell.
ENTRYPOINT ["C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\Enterprise\\Common7\\Tools\\VsDevCmd.bat", "&&", "powershell.exe", "-NoLogo", "-ExecutionPolicy", "Bypass"]
```

After installation, I am getting the below error when I am trying to test webtest

> ```
> MSTest: The term 'MSTest' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
> Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
> At line:1 char:1
> + MSTest
> + ~~~~~~
>    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (MSTest:String) [], >CommandNotFoundException
>    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft currently has an issue with the Visual Studio installer backend. You are probably affected by that. See [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Visual-Studio-Installer-Checking-for-up/10037277#T-N10037573)

Summary: VS Setup is currently down

Answer (score 0):

Try running it like this:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019

# Restore the default Windows shell for correct batch processing.
SHELL ["cmd", "/S", "/C"]

RUN curl -SL --output vs_buildtools.exe https://aka.ms/vs/17/release/vs_buildtools.exe \
    && (start /w vs_buildtools.exe --quiet --wait --norestart --nocache \
        --installPath "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools" \
        --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.AzureBuildTools \
        --remove Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows10SDK.10240 \
        --remove Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows10SDK.10586 \
        --remove Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows10SDK.14393 \
        --remove Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows81SDK \
        || IF "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="3010" EXIT 0) \
    # Cleanup
    && del /q vs_buildtools.exe
```